# zip or forloop two different number of lenth in python

Tags: python

Let me expalain what the real problem is.

i am having two strings :

```
str1="QKHE=K"
str2="Qkhek" #this string donot have '=' inthe same index 'k' is here.
```

i wanted to match the two strings and the desire result should be like

```
result="Qkhe=k"#case sensitive
```

i tried my function :

```
def matchCap(cap1=None,cap2=None):
        if cap1==None or cap2==None:
            return cap1
        else:
            cap1=list(cap1)
            cap2=list(cap2)
            dictionary = (zip(cap1, cap2))
            print(list(dictionary))
            final_cap=[]
            for key, value in dictionary:
                if key=='@' or key=='=':
                    final_cap.append(key)
                else:
                    final_cap.append(value)
            final_cap=''.join(final_cap)
            return final_cap
```

But the zip function not workingwell because of different lengths of list.

so basically i am having two string ..amm like two captcha answers . Gave captcha example for the case sensitive .
i want the result captcha answer is Qkhe=k

Comment: If you want to save `k`, then you should not use `zip`.

Comment: should i try custom zip func ?

Comment: If I execute `print(matchCap("QKHE=K","Qkheke"))`, it outputs `Qkhe=ke`, is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is, when you encounter `@` or `=` in the string, you can append both the key and value, like this...

```py
def matchCap(cap1=None,cap2=None):
    if cap1==None or cap2==None:
        return cap1
    else:
        cap1, cap2 = list(cap1), list(cap2)
        dictionary = (zip(cap1, cap2))
        final_cap = []

        for key, value in dictionary:
            if key in ('@', '='):
                final_cap.append(key)
                final_cap.append(value)
            else:
                final_cap.append(value)

        final_cap = ''.join(final_cap)
        return final_cap

print(matchCap("QKHE=K","Qkhek"))
```

Output:-

```
Qkhe=k
```

Comment: @AkashkumarMallick Anytime!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
str1="QKHE=K"
str2="Qkhek"
def matchCap(cap1=None,cap2=None):
        if cap1==None or cap2==None:
            return cap1
        else:
            cap1=list(cap1)
            cap2=list(cap2)
            final_cap=[]
            cap_2_i = 0
            for cap_1 in range(len(cap1)):
                key = cap1[cap_1]
                value = cap2[cap_2_i]
                if key=='@' or key=='=':
                    final_cap.append(key)
                else:
                    final_cap.append(value)
                    cap_2_i += 1
            final_cap=''.join(final_cap)
            return final_cap
matchCap(str1, str2)
```

Result: `'Qkhe=k'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `zip`, just `for` iterates through it.

Define a variable `i` that represents the index position of the value from `cap2`, and `i` is accumulated each time a value is taken from `cap2`.

```py
def matchCap(cap1=None, cap2=None):
    if cap1 is None or cap2 is None:
        return cap1
    else:
        total_len = len(cap2)
        i = 0
        final_cap = []
        for index, value in enumerate(cap1):
            if value == '@' or value == '=':
                final_cap.append(value)
            else:
                final_cap.append(cap2[i])
                i += 1
                if i >= total_len:
                    break
        final_cap = ''.join(final_cap)
        return final_cap


print(matchCap("QKHE=K", "Qkhek"))

# Qkhe=k
```

Comment: Is it working for matched length ? like print(matchCap("YMUKZ","YmUkZ"))

Comment: @jaykishan It works fine and outputs `YmUkZ`.